# Remove oldest n Items from List using C#

Tags: c#

I am working on a dynamic listing of scores which is frequently updated. Ultimately this is used to produce an overall rating, so older entries (based on some parameters, not time) need to be removed to prevent heavy +/- weighting on the overall. It will be adding multiple values at once from a separate enumeration.

```
  List<int> scoreList = new List<int>();

  foreach(Item x in Items)
  { 
     scoreList.Add(x.score);
  }

  //what I need help with:
  if(scoreList.Count() > (Items.Count() * 3))
  {
      //I need to remove the last set (first in, first out) of values size 
      //Items.Count() from the list
  }
```

If anyone can help it would be much appreciated :) I had to make the code a bit generic because it is written rather cryptically (didn't write the methods).

Comment: if you need FIFO you could use [Queue<int>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx) instead of List<int>.

Comment: CAUTION to future readers: Title originally said ".. *Last* n items", but the accepted answer removes *first* n items, as those are the oldest, based on the code sample given in question. Some answers below do remove "Last n", so read answers carefully to see if they do what you want.

Comment: Don't go for the Queue based implementation if you want to sort your data

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use [`List<T>.RemoveRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y33yd2b5.aspx) - something like this:

```
// number to remove is the difference between the current length
// and the maximum length you want to allow.
var count = scoreList.Count - (Items.Count() * 3);
if (count > 0) {
    // remove that number of items from the start of the list
    scoreList.RemoveRange(0, count);
}
```

You remove from the start of the list, because when you `Add` items they go to the end - so the oldest are at the start.

Answer (score 25):

Try this

```
scoreList.RemoveAt(scoreList.Count-1);
```

And [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132414.aspx) is the MSDN Article

Comment: That removes the most recently added item. OP wants to remove the oldest items

Comment: In my case, i just need to remove the last item, so this works perfectly for me. Thanks.

Comment: RemoveAt is useful for removing *one* item. If removing *N* items, *RemoveRange* is more appropriate. Blorgbeard's answer shows removing *first* N items; to remove *last* N items do `scoreList.RemoveRange(scoreList.Count - N, N);`.  If list might contain less than `N` items, first make sure there are N items: `if (scoreList.Count >= N) ...;` or do `scoreList.RemoveRange(Math.Max(0, scoreList.Count - N), N);`

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using a `List<int>` I would recommend using a `Queue<int>`.  That will give you the FIFO behavior you're looking for.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx for more information on Queues.

```
  Queue<int> scoreList = new Queue<int>();

  foreach(Item x in Items)
  { 
     scoreList.Enqueue(x.score);
  }

  //Or you can eliminate the foreach by doing the following
  //Queue<int> scoreList = new Queue<int>(Items.Select(i => i.score).ToList());

  //Note that Count is a property for a Queue
  while (scoreList.Count > (Items.Count() * 3))
  {
     scoreList.Dequeue();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand your question very well, hope if this is what you want.

```
scoreList.RemoveRange(Items.Count()*3, scoreList.Count()-Items.Count()*3);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to get last n elements from a list with linq

```
      scoreList.Skip(Math.Max(0, scoreList.Count() - N)).Take(N)
```

Answer (score 0):

I toyed around and looked at the method suggested above ( `scoresList.RemoveAt()` ), but it wasn't suited to the situation. What did end up working:

```
 if (...)
 {
    scoresList.RemoveRange(0, scores.Count);
 }
```

Thanks for the help guys

Comment: It seems like that would remove the most recently added scores, not the least recently added scores?